# How to use template variable in a template tag in Django?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I have a custom template tag called cg

```
{% cg %}
```

and I hava a varialbe `{{ status }}`

I need to wrap the result of `{{ status }}` inside a `<special></special>` HTML tag, and then pass into `{%cg  %}`, how to write this code in django template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own filter like this:

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
@stringfilter
def wrap(value, tag):
    return mark_safe("<%(tag)s>%(value)s</%(tag)s>" % {'value': value, 'tag': tag})
```

and use it in template:
`{% cg status|wrap:"special" %}`

Edit-fixed.

Answer (score 0):

["Passing template variables to the tag"](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#passing-template-variables-to-the-tag)